# Pixel tracking code to collect email ids

Tags: wordpress, email, google-analytics, tracking, pixel

I am wanting to be able to keep better track, in real time, the number of people who click through a popover and add their email address.  We have popover ads running on the National Memo website. Currently we are unable to keep track of email names if the user click through it goes to the advertisers page and not ours.

Can I create a pixel that will fire back the email totals and names if possible so that we can track that.  We could have a pixel that either we give to advertiser to add to their landing page, or we include it in our popover.

Comment: Is this Java?  HTML?  PHP?  What are you using?

Comment: @JohnnyBones- I havent worked on it yet as I am unsure where do I start. Can you suggest something about it.

Comment: I actually know nothing about it, but I'm pretty sure it can be done in whatever language you decide to use. The point is, pick a language and then change your tags to include that language. Right now this question is hanging in limbo and very few people with the proper skills will see it.  The tags "tracking" and "pixel" mean almost nothing, but if you decide to go java and add a "Java" tag to your question, Java experts will be more likely to see it.

Comment: @JohnnyBones- thnx for the suggestion...as my website was developed using wordpress, I assume java wont be of help